# Borel measure on a compact metric space

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and write $\mathcal{B}(X)$ for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Also, let $(M, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $\psi: M \rightarrow X$ be an $\mathcal{M}-\mathcal{B}(X)$-measurable map. Define $\mu_{\psi}: \mathcal{B}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by
$$ \mu_{\psi} (B)= \mu (\psi^{-1}(B))$$
for $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$.

**Question** Show that $\mu_{\psi}$ is well defined and that $\mu_{\psi}$ is a Borel measure on $X$.

**Attempt** As far as I understand I need to show that if $B\in\mathcal{B}(X)$, then $\psi^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{M}$ in order to show that $\mu_{\psi}$ is well-defined. But I don't know how can I show that properly.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the definition of measurable map...

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathcal M$-measurability of $\psi$?

Comment: @ Esgeriath How can I show that it is well defined? Should I show the existence of the measure?

Comment: What more is there to show for existence? $\psi^{-1}(B)$ is defined simply by $\psi$ being a function into $X$, and is a measurable set since $\psi$ is measurable. As a measurable set, $\mu(\psi^{-1}(B))$ is defined. Now show that it satisfies the conditions to be a Borel measure.